# angular cdk drag: Restore the default click and drag behavior for text selection in an html input inside a cdkDrag container

Tags: angular, drag, angular-cdk

My template:

```
<div cdkDrag>
  <input id='myInput'>
  <div>Hello World</div>
</div>
```

Now, when an user clicks on the input 'myInput' and tries to select text, the mouse movement gets captured for dragging the cdkDrag container and text cannot be selected.

How can I restore the default click and drag behavior for text selection in an html input inside a cdkDrag container?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue with scrolling overflow.  It would capture the drag container and I was unable to scroll.  My solution was to use a drag handle.  [Customizing the drag area using a handle](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview#customizing-the-drag-area-using-a-handle)

```
<div cdkDrag>
  <input id='myInput'>
  <div>Hello World</div>

  <div cdkDragHandle>
    <svg width="24px" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
      <path d="M10 9h4V6h3l-5-5-5 5h3v3zm-1 1H6V7l-5 5 5 5v-3h3v-4zm14 2l-5-5v3h- 
        3v4h3v3l5-5zm-9 3h-4v3H7l5 5 5-5h-3v-3z"></path>
      <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"></path>
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Edit:** A solution that is more to your question.  I made a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hqvqkb) to play around with it

You could disable drag and drop when a user clicks on that certain element.

```
<div cdkDropList class="example-list" [cdkDropListDisabled]="textClick">
  <div cdkDrag >
    <input id='myInput' (click)="onTextClick()">
    <div>Hello World</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then in your  component

```
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  textClick = false;

  onTextClick(){
    this.textClick = true;
  }
}
```

You would still need to figure out a way to free it up to scroll again